# Extract large archive with 7-zip

Tags: windows-8.1, 7-zip

I have a 76 GB disk image that's split in 28 files (`Foo.7z.001` to `Foo.7z.028`) in "Storage" format and I want to extract it into my D: drive (which has 523 GB available). I've tried all 7-Zip settings:

[image: Options]

... but the software is stubbornly dumping all output into my C: drive (a SSD with only 47 GB left) before (apparently) moving it to final location. Since it's not even smart enough to figure out that 76 won't fit into 47, it runs for half an hour until it freezes with a *Not Enough Disk Space* error message.

I'm using latest stable version (9.20) which is already 4 years old. Did I misunderstood what "Working folder" stands for? Is it a known issue? Is there a better archiver with 7-Zip support?

Comment: Silly question, are the 28 files currently located on the `D:\\` drive prior to being unzipped?

Comment: lots of compresses bust out into (system defined) temps.  you indicated what drive it breaks out to. Where on the drive did it go?  Could be you could put (system defined) temps on a different drive. Depending on what occurs putting temps on a less used drive, could be speedy for other things too using more "hardware" at more locations.  Some compresses have been told to keep the existing folder structure, so they finish where the Maker of the compress decided they would go.  7-z works with all manners of compresses, it could be these folder options do not apply to all of the "engines" dlls ?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus - They were previously on an external USB disk (so D: used to have 523+76 free GB). I moved them later to D:. I'm getting C: filled in both cases.

Comment: @Psycogeek - Output goes to `%temp%` (`C:\Users\alvaro\AppData\Local\Temp`), I know because I have to remove the temporary file myself when 7-Zip freezes.

Comment: I see, what if you set the choice to "Current" and use the "Extract Here" option while the files are on the `D:\\` drive?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Are you dragging and dropping the files using the GUI?

If you use the option in the shell to "Extract to here" or even the button "Extract" in the file manager GUI, that should not happen anymore, as 7-Zip should be able to bypass the need to use a temporary directory altogether.

This is explained in the *Why does drag-and-drop archive extraction from 7-Zip to Explorer use temp files?* [FAQ](http://www.7-zip.org/faq.html#user_faq) entry:

> 7-Zip doesn't know folder path of drop target. Only Windows Explorer
>   knows exact drop target. And Windows Explorer needs files (drag
>   source) as decompressed files on disk. So 7-Zip extracts files from
>   archive to temp folder and then 7-Zip notifies Windows Explorer about
>   paths of these temp files. Then Windows Explorer copies these files to
>   drop target folder.
>
> To avoid temp file usage, you can use Extract command of 7-Zip or
>   drag-and-drop from 7-Zip to 7-Zip.

Answer (score 0):

[Bandizip](http://www.bandisoft.com/bandizip) says on their webpage that their program supports 7zip.001 files, it has an option to set a temporary file window as well. Hopefully it's going to help you, currently I don't have very big files to test it by myself. Here's a picture of the option window:

[image]